# The helium balloon and buoyancy

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, buoyancy, weight

Well I noticed something with a helium balloon which a little weight was tied to its rope to avoid it flying away. When the weight is on the ground and the rope is taut, I pulled it down a little and let it go. It flew up and when the rope was taut again, it kept on going higher with a negative acceleration, traveled some height and then stopped and fell down again. Then I pulled it down much more than the last time, expecting it to gain a greater velocity due to buoyancy which is bigger than its weight, when the rope becomes taut, and travel a longer height, but what happened was it traveled a much smaller distance. Any explanation??

Comment: The rope weights

Comment: @Alchimista I think the weight of the rope is negligible. And it is also present in the first case, why not effecting that?

Comment: It is like a spring.  Your other observation seems weird

Comment: You say that, "when the rope was taut again, it kept on going higher with a negative acceleration […]" Can I just check that the rope is now raising the weight, having lifted it off the ground?

Comment: Yes, the rope has lifted the weight, and in the first case the rope lifts it higher than the second.

Comment: It always there but more you displace the balloon the weight will act along a longer path.

Comment: In other words W = F × L.